# Proper way to get counts from multiple left joins

Tags: mysql, sql, count, left-join

I am attempting to build a query that will pull all the columns from one table, and also adds some counts from another related table, using left joins to find items from this table related to each column in the initial table.

So far I have this:

```
SELECT table1.*,
       count(table2_c1.ID) as column1_count,
       count(table2_c2.ID) as column2_count
from table1
left join (select * from table2
           where table2.COLUMN_1 = 1) as table2_c1
    on table1.ID = table2_c1.TABLE1_ID
left join (select * from table2
           where table2.COLUMN_2 = 1) as table2_c2
    on table1.ID = table2_c2.TABLE1_ID
group by table1.ID
having ANOTHER_COLUMN = 1;
```

But this takes about 5 seconds to execute, and I haven't added anywhere near the amount of counts the final statement will contain. Is there any better way of doing this? I apologize for such a poor explanation of the problem, I'm rather new to SQL.

Comment: [sarcasm] _fairly large dataset_ and _several thousand rows per table_ is not serious in the same sentence. [/sarcasm] Welcome to SO to get an answer on performance issue like this , it is better to show the DDL of your tables (including indexes), and the execution plan

Comment: @ThomasG heh, removed that statement from the question. Unfortunately I can't really share much information about the tables due to sensitive data contained in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to do double joins, use `case` expressions to do conditional aggregation instead:

```
SELECT table1.*,
       count(case when table2.COLUMN_1 = 1 then 1 end) as column1_count,
       count(case when table2.COLUMN_2 = 1 then 1 end) as column2_count
from table1
left join table2
    on table1.ID = table2.TABLE1_ID
group by table1.ID
having ANOTHER_COLUMN = 1;
```

Comment: That's great! Thanks, the query still takes longer than I'd like, but I'm guessing that's unavoidable due to the size of dataset and performance of the machine. Adding more counts now makes negligible difference to the execution time, cheers.

Comment: You can try and add `AND (table2.COLUMN_1 = 1 OR table2.COLUMN_2 = 1)` to the `ON` clause and see what happens.

Comment: sorry, perhaps this would be better in another question, but when I add a left join to another table, and then get a count from that table in the same way you showed me, it results in the original counts being incorrect, any idea what I could be doing wrong?